# how to make color change to white when hovering over button

Tags: html, css

The text color only changes when I hover over the text. I want the text color to change to white when I hover over the button.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong, please?

```css
#callbtn {
  border: 1px solid #507487;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #507487;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#callbtn:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#callbtn a {
  color: #507487;
}

#callbtn a:hover {
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #callbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

#callbtn i {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="m-2 text-center" id="callbtn"><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i><a href="tel:+441225xxxxxx">Call</a></p>
```

Comment: Weird that the link is not 100% of the button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callbtn:hover triggering when the button is hovered over, and a:hover is triggering when the link is hovered over. Which is why this is happening, you are hovering over the button but not setting the colour of the link. The CSS below will set a style to the child link when button is hovered over.

```
#callbtn:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS need to apply the color on hover of the button, not the hover of the link

```
#callbtn:hover a {
   color: #FFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to set your button up like this:

```css
.callbtn {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #507487;
  background-color: white;
  color: #507487;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.callbtn:hover {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

.callbtn i {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .callbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="callbtn" href="tel:+441225xxxxxx">
  <i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i>Call
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit weird but some JavaScript solves the problem:

```js
var callButton = document.body.querySelector("#callbtn");
var callButtonLnk = document.body.querySelector("#callbtn a");
callButton.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  callButtonLnk.style.color = "white";
})
callButton.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  callButtonLnk.style.color = "#507487";
})
```